# How to access data returned from Ajax post method call with index just like an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code and it is not working to success function. Is there a possibility that I am not specifying in the right way tr and td elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").blur(function () {
        //alert("ilir");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { "barkodi": $(this).val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('tr[class!="info"]').remove().after(function () {
                    $.each(function (index, data) {
                        $("tr").append(
                            $("<tr></tr>").html(
                            $("<td></td>").text(data[0].Barkodi),
                            $("<td></td>").text(data[0].Emri),
                            $("<td></td>").text(data[0].Cmimi),
                            $("<td></td>").text(data[0].Sasia))
                            );
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
})
```

And here is my controller and action method I dont where is my bug here :(

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult Index(string barkodi)
    {
        var produkti = _context.Produktets.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Barkodi == barkodi);

        List<ProduktetCustom> prod = new List<ProduktetCustom>();
        ProduktetCustom produkt = new ProduktetCustom()
        {
            Barkodi = produkti.Barkodi,
            Emri = produkti.Emri,
            Sasia = produkti.Sasia,
            Cmimi = produkti.Cmimi,
            Pershkrimi = produkti.Pershkrimi,
            IsDeleted = produkti.IsDeleted,
            DataModifikimit = produkti.DataModifikimit,
            DataShtimit = produkti.DataShtimit
        };

        prod.Add(produkt);
        return Json(prod,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: is it entering the success function? 
add an error function, error:function(xhr){console.log(xhr)}
check what the response text is

Comment: Do you see any console errors?

Comment: I think you have forgot to give url to the ajax request

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forEach` function defined in `Array` instead of `$.each`.

Your code will look like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('tr[class!="info"]').remove().after(function () {
        data.forEach(function (item, index) {
            $("tr").append(
                $("<tr></tr>").html(
                    $("<td></td>").text(item.Barkodi),
                    $("<td></td>").text(item.Emri),
                    $("<td></td>").text(item.Cmimi),
                    $("<td></td>").text(item.Sasia)
                )
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct; the issue is how you're adding the elements in the `html()` method. It accepts only a string or a function. You're also looping through the `data` array, but repeatedly adding only the content from the first item. You're also attempting to place content `after()` an element which has been removed, which won't work.

Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
  var html = data.map(function(o) {
    return `<tr><td>${o.Barkodi}</td><td>${o.Emri}</td><td>${o.Cmimi}</td><td>${o.Sasia}</td></tr>`;
  }).join('');
  $('table tbody').append(html);
}
```

```js
var data = [{
  Barkodi: 'Barkodi 1',
  Emri: 'Emri 1',
  Cmimi: 'Cmimi 1',
  Sasia: 'Cmimi 1',
}, {
  Barkodi: 'Barkodi 2',
  Emri: 'Emri 2',
  Cmimi: 'Cmimi 2',
  Sasia: 'Cmimi 2',
}]


var html = data.map(function(o) {
  return `<tr><td>${o.Barkodi}</td><td>${o.Emri}</td><td>${o.Cmimi}</td><td>${o.Sasia}</td></tr>`;
}).join('');
console.log(html);
$('table tbody').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can try `parseJSON`.

```
var objArray = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(function (index, objArray) {
//other stuff
});
```